# Reverse list and delay display

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have a simple script on my site to reverse the display of a list.

```
$('li.shoplist').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

It works great, but the reversal of the list occurs after / during page load — and thus the list (which is largely imagery) appears and then snaps into reverse order, which looks a little clunky.

Is there a way to delay the display of the list until *after* it has reversed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can hide the list and you can show it when it is already reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the visibility to hidden until you finish your flip. 
Do not use `display:none` because it will mess up the rest of your screen.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the style `display: none` in your HTML, something like:

```
<ul style="display:none">
```

..and then during the loading of the page you show the list at the end:

```
$(function() {

    $('li.shoplist').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().prepend(this);
    }).parent().show();

})
```

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested well by O_Z

```
$(function() {

    $('li.shoplist').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().prepend(this);
    }).parent().css('opacity', '1');

})
```